# Laravel migration drop column with primary key (error)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have already checked the other topics but no solution worked with me. I tried the last time:

```
public function up()
{
    if(Schema::hasColumn('orders_products_variations','id')) {
        Schema::table('orders_products_variations',function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id')->change();
            $table->dropPrimary();
            $table->dropColumn('id');
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id');
    });
}
```

And the error message is :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: alter table `orders_products_variations` drop primary key)

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like `id` is defined as auto increment, so it must be the primary key. You should be able to just drop the id column without any of the other hoops.

Comment: i already tried to drop only the id column but it didn't work too

Comment: You might have to split this up into two `Schema::table` calls. The first will drop the primary key, while the second drops the entire column.

Comment: Thx but i have also tried

Comment: Wich column you try to delete ?

Comment: Only the first one (id) because i don't need to this

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I've found myself with similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

> A migration class contains two methods: up and down. The up method is
>   used to add new tables, columns, or indexes to your database, while
>   the down method should reverse the operations performed by the up
>   method.

**Dropping Columns**

> To drop a column, use the `dropColumn` on the Schema builder inside down method

```
if (Schema::hasColumn('table_name', 'column_name')) {
    Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->dropColumn('column_name');
    });
}
```

**Adding / Dropping Columns**

> PS When you have to add a new column to the existing table in Laravel, you must
>   create new migration .

```
php artisan make:migration add_column_to_table
```

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206361/aravel-migration-drop-column-with-primary-key-error

Comment: This is entirely wrong.  `up()` is not only for adding, and `down()` is not only for dropping.  OP's question is an example.

Comment: @Don'tPanic you may refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#migration-structure

Comment: Hmm well that is interesting :D However I still think it is entirely wrong, OP's question is a perfect example, I also do this all the time.  Schemas change, sometimes you need to remove columns - how would you do it except with a migration?

Comment: I never used up() method before to delete column(s). However, since  down() method is called when you run php artisan migrate:rollback, i use it to delete columns, tables ...

Comment: So you literally have to `migrate:rollback` to do a forward migration? What happens when you later need to do a new migration - `migrate` will process both that migration's `up()`, and the new one's.  If your `up()` is empty, it means you are missing the entire point of migrations, to be able to maintain a history of how the DB looked at any time in version control.  If your `up()` is the reverse of the `down()` (as it should be), then your deleted columns will be added again ... ?